# LINQ Group by Clause with Where clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am learning LINQ. Can anybody please help me to solve the following problem!

From **Northwind**'s **Customers** and **Orders** tables:

I want to "**Find all Customers who have done more than 20 Orders**"

The Query in SQL Server for the same is:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID in (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders GROUP BY CustomerID HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 20)
```

But, I could not able to write the equivalent in LINQ.

I have tried like below:

```
var customers = ctx.Customers.Where(o => o.CustomerID.Count() > 20).GroupBy(o => o.CustomerID);
```

I am geting the following error in Event Log:

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpCompileException 
    Exception message: e:\Ashok\WEB\VS2012\CSHWEB\CSHWEB\LINQ01.aspx(17): error CS0103: The name 'Orders' does not exist in the current context

The reason is that the dependent Orders table might not be loaded yet. But, I am not understanding how to make it work!

Comment: In which context are you using LINQ? Linq2Sql? EntityFramework? Model First? Code First? Fluent?

Comment: @mehrandvd: LINT to SQL. How does the context matter here?

Comment: @Ashokkumar see msdn [Walkthrough: Creating LINQ to SQL Classes (O/R Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384428.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your relations between objects should be properly configured. If you're using Entity Framework just mark `Orders` property in `Customers` entity as `virtual` this will allow lazy loading. Then your query will be much simpler. Otherwise you can still start from `Orders` instead of `Customers`:

```
var customers = ctx.Orders.GroupBy(c => c.CustomerID)
                             .Where(x => x.Count() > 20)
                             .SelectMany(g => g.Select(o => o.Customer));
```

And for customers (with `virtual` Orders collection) pretty straightforward:

```
var customers = ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Count() > 20);
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your reply. But, your code is not compiling and showing error at g.Value

Answer (score 1):

If customers and orders are related (1:MANY) and you have set up your object model to reflect this you could do:

```
var customers = ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Count() > 20);
```

If not then:

```
var customerIds = ctx.Orders.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerID)
.Where(x => x.Count() > 20);
.SelectMany(x => x.CustomerID);

var customers = ctx.Customers.Where(x => customerIds.Contains(x.CustomerID));
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. But, your code is not working. I am getting the following error:
The name 'Orders' does not exist in the current context
Request you to verify the code before sending reply.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var customers = from c in Customers where c.Orders.Count() > 20 select c;
customers.GroupBy(o => o.CustomerID);
```

Comment: Hi,
Your code is giving the following error:
The name 'Orders' does not exist in the current context
Request you to verify the code once before sending.

Answer (score 1):

try use [join..into clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311040.aspx) something like this

```
var customers = from c in ctx.Customers
                join o in ctx.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into orders
                where orders.Count()>20
                select c;
```

Comment: Hi,
Your code is giving the following error: "The name 'Orders' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Ashokkumar see msdn [Walkthrough: Creating LINQ to SQL Classes (O/R Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384428.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In order to write to such query, you need to use a database relation (Navigation Property). This relation should be declared in your context as `Customer.Orders`. After then, you can use Linq to query the context.
Check this out for an example which describes what you need.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

However you can declare context like:

```
public partial class Northwind : DataContext
{
   public Table<Customer> Customers;
   public Table<Order> Orders;
   public Northwind(string connection): base(connection) {}
}
```

and you should define your Customer class like:

```
[Table(Name="Customers")]
public class Customer
{
   [Column(Id=true)]
   public string CustomerID;
   ...
   private EntitySet<Order> _Orders;
   [Association(Storage="_Orders", OtherKey="CustomerID")]
   public EntitySet<Order> Orders {
      get { return this._Orders; }
      set { this._Orders.Assign(value); }
   }
}
```

then you can query it like the other answers said.

Comment: Hope you have seen my comments for other answers.